# showing list items from xml using growing property

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to display list of items in list. I want to show list items 4 by default when again click on more it has to get 4 more items and when again click on more it has to get 4 more items, and so on.

I followed many blogs and tried like below:

```
<List id="list" 
  items="{ path: '/ProductSet', sorter: { path: 'productId' }, groupHeaderFactory: '.createGroupHeader' }"              
  growing="true" growingThreshold="4" growingScrollToLoad="true"
  updateFinished="onUpdateFinished">
```

Each time it has to hit the OData and fetch records when click on more button. But by doing like above I am not able to achieve my goal.

I am getting all records in single call. In the Network tab I am able to see query:

```
ProductSet?$skip=0&$top=4&$orderby=productId
```

Do we need to implement skip and top in OData also or can we achieve without implementing in OData?

Comment: I am not able to understand your que.  "growingThreshold" is there to limit number of records fetched in backend call. It helps improve performance. Do you want to get all data at once, and display them in set of 4?

Comment: i dont want to get all data at once performance issues will come when we have huge data.....i want to get data based on threshold value...and when again click on more next 4 records..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get only 4 from the service and load the next 4 on demand, yes you'll need to implement `$skip` and `$top`, but also the count request (inline or explicit) so that SAPUI5 knows how many entries there are.

You can also load all entries at once and handle sorting / show more on the frontend by adding `parameters: { operationMode: 'Client' }` to the items binding.